# Is there a way to get brackets out of a code's output? I would like to print the code out in a user-friendly way

Tags: ruby

I was able to figure out how to get the indexes that have hold the max value in an array.

Example:

```
b = [2, 3, 4, 4]
c = [2, 3, 4, 4].max
a=b.each_index.select{|i| b[i]== c}
puts a

=> [2, 3]
```

I don't want to get `[2, 3]`; I want to get rid of the brackets. Additionally, I want to add `1` to the indexes to get: `3, 4`. I don't want to start the count at 0.

Ideally, the output would read:

```
=> 3, 4
```

Comment: Your code does not do what your code example shows. You have a syntax error in `b [i]= c` and `a` does not equal the value you have listed. If you want help then you must make sure that the code example you provide in your question actually works the way you expect it to work.

Comment: It should work this way: a=b.each_index.select{|i| b[i]== c}

Comment: That still doesn't make `a` equal what you say it does. And once you finally figure out what your code sample should **actually** be, you should edit your original post. Don't post it as a comment.

Comment: What does the "hash rocket" `=>` in your example indicate? A return value or the output? Because I cannot reproduce it. If `a` is `[2, 3]`, then `puts a` will _print_ `2` and `3` on separate lines (without commas or brackets). And it will _return_ `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get the output you want would be to use the [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-join) method

i.e.

```
puts [2, 3].join(', ')
# => 2, 3
```

If you then want the ordinal for each match instead of the index, the easiest would be to just map those to index + 1

```
[2, 3].map{ |i| i + 1 }
# => [3, 4]
```

Altogether, your assignment and `puts` statement could then be written as

```
a = b.each_index.select{ |i| b[i] == c }.map{ |i| i + 1 }.join(', ')
puts a

=> 3, 4
```

Comment: You could also use `.map(&:succ)` to map each element to its successor.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-map), [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index), [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-select), [`Array#first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-first), [`Array#max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-max), [`Array#last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-last) and [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-join)

```
b = [2, 3, 4, 4]

b.map.with_index(1).select { |a| a.first == b.max }.map(&:last).join(", ") # => "3, 4"
```

```
# Step 1
b.map.with_index(1).to_a # => [[2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]

# Step 2
b.map.with_index(1).select { |a| a.first == b.max } # => [[4, 3], [4, 4]]

# Step 3
b.map.with_index(1).select { |a| a.first == b.max }.map(&:last) # => [3, 4]

# Step 4
b.map.with_index(1).select { |a| a.first == b.max }.map(&:last).join(", ") # => "3, 4"
```

You can use it as your own method

```
def max_elements_ids(ary)
  ary.
    map.
    with_index(1).
    select { |a| a.first == b.max }.
    map(&:last).
    join(", ")
end

puts max_elements_ids([2, 3, 4, 4]) # will print 3, 4
puts max_elements_ids([2, 4, 3, 4, 4]) # will print 2, 4, 5
```

Comment: Calling `b.max` within the block will calculate the maximum value again for each element, although it doesn't change.

Comment: @Stefan, yes,  to optimize speed it's better to calculate max value once. Before this block